# Why rust complains about Self's unknown size in one trait and doesn't in another similar trait.?

Tags: rust

Consider below two traits

```rust
trait FromSomeStr {
    // rust doesn't complain about Self unknown size in this trait
    fn from_input(input: String) -> Self;
}

trait FromOtherStr: FromSomeStr
{
    // rust complains about Self unknown size in this trait, but doesn't in FromSomeStr trait
    fn from_some_other_str(input: String) -> Self { 
        Self::from_input(input)
    }
}
```

Rust compiler response:

```rust
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:9:46
  |
9 |     fn from_some_other_str(input: String) -> Self { 
  |                                              ^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
help: consider further restricting `Self`
  |
9 |     fn from_some_other_str(input: String) -> Self where Self: Sized { 
  |                                                   +++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |         Self::from_input(input)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
help: consider further restricting `Self`
   |
9  |     fn from_some_other_str(input: String) -> Self where Self: Sized { 
   |                                                   +++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

Both methods `from_input` and `from_some_other_str` return Self and we don't know about it's size unless some struct implements both the traits.

Rust strangely asks to constraint Self with Sized trait in `FromOtherStr` trait but doesn't in `FromSomeStr`. Why this behavior ?

Playgorund Link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=60bfb31c844dd7b765b7921f64b808ce

I expected rust not to give any error

Comment: It seems it's related to providing a default function implementation, rather than super trait requirements.

Comment: It seems the reason is that only trait method bodies with default implementation are type checked, but I'm not confident enough to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a Rust expert, and this is more of a gut feeling than actual knowledge. Please take this answer with a grain of salt.

**Edited** after feedback from @ChayimFriedman:

Both should fail. A return value always has to be `Sized`, because it has to live in memory somewhere, and the compiler has to know its size for that.

So the real question is not why the second case fails, but why the first case doesn't.

@ChayimFriedman seems to have looked at the compiler code, and the answer is that the compiler only type checks trait functions with a default implementation.

Whether or not this is a good design decision is not the subject of discussion here, but that's at least the reason for the behavior you see.

Either way, the takeaway is: always use `Sized` as a trait requirement if one of your functions returns `Self`.

---

Original answer:

Let's simplify your problem:

```rust
pub trait FromSomeStr {
    // rust doesn't complain about Self unknown size in this trait
    fn from_input(input: String) -> Self;
}

pub trait FromOtherStr: FromSomeStr {
    // rust complains about Self unknown size in this trait, but doesn't in FromSomeStr trait
    fn from_some_other_str(input: String) {
        Self::from_input(input);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `Self` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         Self::from_input(input);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
help: consider further restricting `Self`
  |
8 |     fn from_some_other_str(input: String) where Self: Sized {
  |                                           +++++++++++++++++
```

You can see it still happens even if you don't return anything. The problem here is the call itself.

It's gone when we remove the return from the called function:

```rust
pub trait FromSomeStr {
    // rust doesn't complain about Self unknown size in this trait
    fn from_input(input: String);
}

pub trait FromOtherStr: FromSomeStr {
    // rust complains about Self unknown size in this trait, but doesn't in FromSomeStr trait
    fn from_some_other_str(input: String) {
        Self::from_input(input);
    }
}
```

So the question is, why so?

It makes sense to me why Rust complains about calling the function, because that's where the object gets created. Not knowing the size of the return value of the called function makes it impossible to compile it.

I don't know why it doesn't complain at the definition already, though. Someone else might have to explain that. But my guess is that errors like this only manifest at the calling site, not at the definition site.

---

Example in the Rust library:

[`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) is a trait that behaves very similar to your `FromSomeStr`. But it works:

```rust
pub trait FromOtherStr: Default {
    // rust complains about Self unknown size in this trait, but doesn't in FromSomeStr trait
    fn from_some_other_str(_input: String) -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
}
```

So why is that?

If you look at the [implementation of `Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/default.rs.html#102), you can see:

```rust
pub trait Default: Sized {
    // ...
}
```

And I guess the `Sized` here was introduced specifically because otherwise it would be impossible to `return` a `Self` object.

Comment: Thanks for sharing different scenarios.

Comment: @akhildevelops I hope it helped in some way, as I wasn't able to come up with an actual in-depth explanation.

Comment: The call does not matter. It errors with either the call or the return type, if the method has a default implementation.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman How would you create a return type if not calling a function that returns `Self`? :) You can't directly create a generic type

Comment: @Finomnis Via `panic!()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yah I just got it as you posted it :) Ok! What's the explanation then why the default implementation makes the difference? Why does the `FromSomeStr` trait not fail already, given that it's impossible to ever be called?

Comment: @Finomnis As I posted as a comment to the OP, from inspection of the compiler code it looks like only trait methods with default implementation are type checked.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Well the question whether this is intended behaviour is pretty pointless in a language without formal specification ... but I wonder if that should get changed.

Comment: @Finomnis I guess it wasn't intentional, just avoiding type checking of methods without bodies, but changing it now is too late.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks for your input :) I changed my answer accordingly.